# make batches with own csv file python

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, neural-network, batch-processing

I have a python code for the MNIST dataset using Tensorflow.
Session is the following:

```
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
            print('Epoch: ', epoch, ' completed out of: ', hm_epochs, ' loss: ', epoch_loss)
    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

    print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

The line:

```
epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
```

is making everytime new batches with the size 100.

My question is, how to replace this line with a new line that makes for me new batches if I have my own CSV file (which is a list of lists)? 
My current code looks like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
        epoch_loss = 0
        for _ in range(len(training_data_list) // batch_size):
            epoch_x, epoch_y = training_data_list.nextbatch(batch_size)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
            epoch_loss += c
        print('Epoch: ', epoch, ' completed out of: ', hm_epochs, ' loss: ', epoch_loss)
    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

    print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: inputs, y: targets}))
```

Where the "nextbatch" is a function I defined. But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'nextbatch'
```

I appreciate any suggestion :D

By the way, "training_data_list" comes from:

```
stops = open('.../Desktop/stops_train.csv', 'r')
training_data_list  = stops.readlines()
stops.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an object which handles the indexing.
You need to implement nextbatch function inside that object.
You can look at implementation of nextbatch in the mnist.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Meanwhile I used this: 
    for _ in range(len(training_data_list)):
                batch_x = inputs_train[_*batch_size:(_+1)*batch_size]
                batch_y = targets_train[_*batch_size:(_+1)*batch_size]
and it worked.